# How to restore removed (.removeAttr()) attributes

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

So here's my problem, I used .removeAttr() as a work around in disabling inline style, now there's an instance where I need restore the attribute that i had removed. Is it still possible? or what can you suggest alternative solution i could use.

The trigger for my removeAttr() is media query from my browser. when the browser is being resize, the position of the element in the dom also change. By default, my html has an inline style that is being used. But when it is resize down, it should move the element on a different postion and when it returened to the original scale or in a wider view, it should restore the removed attribute as well.

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

jQuery(function() {

    var pause = 100; // will only process code within delay(function() { ... }) every 100ms.

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {

        delay(function() {

            var width = jQuery(window).width();

            if( width >= 958 && width <= 1400 ) {
                if(jQuery(".box1 #move_me").length == 0) {
                    // needs to restore the removed "style" attribute
                    jQuery("#move_me").appendTo(jQuery(".box1"));
                }
            } else if( width >= 768 && width <= 959 ) {

            } else if( width >= 480 && width <= 767 ) {
               jQuery("#move_me").insertAfter(".box2 .insert_below").removeAttr("style");
            } else if( width <= 479 ) {
               jQuery("#move_me").insertAfter(".box3 .insert_below").removeAttr("style");
            }

        }, pause );

    });

    jQuery(window).resize();

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFzy7/embedded/result/ (resize to see changes) - if you notice, by default if you're in a wider screen (eg, above 960px or 1200px), "hello world" should be in red and is in an arial font. when you resize, it moves to another div/box. But when your resize it back to the wide screen, the text is not in it's original look (red-arial).

Is there a way i can restore the removed attribute? if no, what do you think is a work around to my problem?

Thank You.

Comment: `$(".box2 .insert_below").data('oldstyle', $(this).prop('style')).removeAttr("style");`, so later you can use `.data('oldstyle')` to retrieve it.

Comment: If you removed the style, you can't re-add it unless you stored it's value before you removed it.

Comment: IMHO (if you have control over the page markup) the solution is to just not use an inline style in the first place

Comment: I would recommend to use CSS classes and you could use for example `.toggleClass('className')`

Comment: yes, the process might have been easier if i can just use classes instead of inline. but no, i don't have control with the markup of what im trying to manipulate.

Comment: FYI, there was a `)` error in my code on my answer before. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to give the element (or some element or even document) a data value of the style before removing it. Then you could recall that style via that data later.

Like so:

```
 jQuery("#move_me")
      .insertAfter(".box2 .insert_below")
      .data("reStyle", jQuery("#move_me").attr("style"))
      .removeAttr("style").removeAttr("style")
```

And then later:

```
 jQuery("#move_me").attr("style", jQuery("#move_me").data("reStyle"))
```

## Example

Comment: This works! i'll be using data more often in the future :) Thank You, @SpYk3HH

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use CSS classes, but since you can't manipulate the markup. I would simply store the style as a string in a variable.

So, to get the style use `var divStyle = $("#move_me).attr("style");` then to remove the attribute, and restore it using `$("move_me").attr("style",divStyle);`.